# Bar graph with multiple data points

Tags: visualforce-charting

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart that will have a variable number of data points in it.
The example in the [Visualforce Developers Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_charting_appearance_bar_charts.htm|SkinName=webhelp) shows three datapoints being referenced.

I have tried using a list of decimals in place of the three attributes in the example. I get the labels for the x axis but no bars.

Is it possible to pass through a list or other data structure that would allow for a variable number of data points for the bar stacks? 
(e.g. 10 points for each stack when the chart is rendered today but tomorrow there could be 15 points for each stack)

Is what I am trying to do possible in Visualforce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page and controller demonstrates what I think you want. The controller supplies the comma-separated field names and titles for the stacked data; the Apex class (called `Item` here) that supplies the data to the chart must have fields of matching names that are populated with data.

Chart:

[image: chart example]

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="A">
<apex:chart data="{!data}" height="400" width="500">
    <apex:legend position="left"/>
    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" title="Closed Won" grid="true"
        fields="{!fields}" dashSize="2">
        <apex:chartLabel/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Stacked Bars">
        <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
    </apex:axis>
    <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" stacked="true"
        xField="name" yField="{!fields}" title="{!titles}"/>
</apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class A {

    public Item[] data {
        get {
            return new Item[] {
                    new Item('Jan'),
                    new Item('Feb'),
                    new Item('Mar'),
                    new Item('Apr')
                    };
        }
    }

    // Vary these arrays to determine how many are stacked
    private String[] stackFields = new String[] {'data1', 'data2', 'data3'};
    private String[] stackTitles = new String[] {'Acme', 'Berlitz', 'Concorde'};

    public String fields {
        get {
            return String.join(stackFields, ',');
        }
    }
    public String titles {
        get {
            return String.join(stackTitles, ',');
        }
    }

    public class Item {

        public String name;

        public Integer data1;
        public Integer data2;
        public Integer data3;
        public Integer data4;
        public Integer data5;
        public Integer data6;
        public Integer data7;
        public Integer data8;
        public Integer data9;
        public Integer data10;
        public Integer data11;
        public Integer data12;
        public Integer data13;
        public Integer data14;
        public Integer data15;

        Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            data1 = r();
            data2 = r();
            data3 = r();
            data4 = r();
            data5 = r();
            data6 = r();
            data7 = r();
            data8 = r();
            data9 = r();
            data10 = r();
            data11 = r();
            data12 = r();
            data13 = r();
            data14 = r();
            data15 = r();
        }

        Integer r() {
            return (Math.random() * 10000).intValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keith, I have tried to use the standard object (opportunity) to tried out instead of generating random numbers but the graph is not showing at all, do you have a sample code that demonstrate what you have done using standard or custom object?

Comment: is this applicable on Radar Chart?I 've try it but it not display,

Comment: @unidha I don't know.